# asp.net timeout after inactivity, clarity question

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm trying to understand the difference between these 3 timeouts.
There a numerous threads on these subjects,

In addition to the below, I'm not sure if there is another setting somewhere that I'm overlooking...

```
IIS Session State config: ASP.NET_SessionId Cookie set to timeout after 20 minutes

< sessionStatemode= "InProc" cookieless= "UseCookies"regenerateExpiredSessionId= "true"timeout= "60" />

< formsloginUrl= "Authentication/SignIn.aspx"timeout= "121"slidingExpiration= "true"cookieless= "UseCookies" />
```

Here's my notes:

The Forms Authentication Timeout value sets the amount of time in minutes that the authentication cookie / ticket is set to be valid, meaning, that after value number of minutes, the cookie / ticket will expire and the user will no longer be authenticated—they will be redirected to the login page automatically.   The slidingExpiration=true value is basically saying that as long as the user makes a request within the timeout value, they will continue to be authenticated

The SessionState timeout value sets the amount of time a Session State provider is required to hold data in memory (or whatever backing store is being used, SQL Server, OutOfProc, etc) for a particular session. For example, if you put an object in Session using the value in your example, this data will be removed after 30 minutes. The user may still be authenticated but the data in the Session may no longer be present. The Session Timeout value is always reset after every request.

**Question1** why would someone configure all of these values differently.  Why wouldn't they be set the same?

**Question2** I assume the IIS session state cookie time takes precedence and kicks the user out after 20 idle minutes?  (It appears I'm being logged out after 20 minutes, that's why i think this).  Can't understand why then I would want to keep the login ticket valid for 60 minutes, and then the sessionstate data for 121 mins (which seems like a very odd number to choose)